# Google Drive API v2 - Single-parent model enforcement is there an issue if enforceSingleParent is not set to TRUE?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

The Google Drive developer notification regarding the removal of support for files to have multiple parents (ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/multi-parenting), there is mention of setting the parameter 'enforceSingleParent' to TRUE when inserting a file to "opt in to API behavior that aims for all items to have exactly one parent."

I've upgraded my Drive API v2 to the latest Java version of 1.30.10, however the Insert class does not have a setter for 'enforceSingleParent'.  I have ensured that I no longer require multiple file parents for any of my API calls and always set the parents value to a single parent folder ID.  However the description of this value in the API makes me wonder if there is any other requirement for its use to ensure a smooth migration come Sept 30.

Other than ensuring you don't set a file to have multiple parents, is there anything else required for to support this single parent migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Github source code for Drive.java you will see that such setter actually exists.

At line [2715](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/dfec1c7c6df860f0a5e63616cbd2e0a4bee326f4/clients/google-api-services-drive/v2/1.30.1/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.java#L2715) in Drive.java

```
      /**
       * Set to true to opt in to API behavior that aims for all items to have exactly one parent.
       * This parameter only takes effect if the item is not in a shared drive. If the child's owner
       * makes the request, the child is removed from all current folders and placed in the
       * requested folder. Any other requests that increase the number of the child's parents fail,
       * except when the canAddMyDriveParent file capability is true and a single parent is being
       * added.
       */
      public Insert setEnforceSingleParent(java.lang.Boolean enforceSingleParent) {
        this.enforceSingleParent = enforceSingleParent;
        return this;
      }
```

Use example:

```
File file = service.files().insert(fileContent).setEnforceSingleParent(true).execute();
```

It might be a linter issue not recognizing this method. In IntelliJ IDEA it works fine for example.

Here some instructions on how to correctly update the dependencies in your project:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-drive/v2/1.30.1#installation

### Reference

[Drive v2 1.30.1 GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-drive/v2/1.30.1)

[Drive v2 Files insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

Comment: Thanks, my bumble, IDE needed dependencies refreshed